# Eurostar London-Brussels train after transition period

Tags: uk, paperwork, brexit

Will it still be possible to take the train from London-Brussels with an EU ID only or will I have to take a passport along with me, and will it be even stamped at entry? All of these after the transition period.

Comment: What do you refer to? Brexit?

Comment: Yes, Brexit (edited by mod)

Comment: It's just that over the past days 90 % of the postings related to COVID. I had to think, what you possibly meant.

Comment: I don’t think anyone knows what will happens after the end of the transition period. If you are doing your planning, you should probably anticipate getting and using a passport.

Comment: @us er It seems pretty logical to conclude that a passport will be required.

Comment: Obviously after the end of this coronavirus

Comment: At present it assumed that things will remain as they are for short term visits. Since a lot of the UK Border control is done electronically (including the collection of exit data) there may be no need for a passport.

Comment: But will there be a 90/180 rule? I'll move to Brussels in the future (after this outbreak ofc) and I'll be needing to go to London periodically because I'd have to see a few brothers there (like once every 2/3 weeks).

Comment: Obviously I won't work there.

Comment: @Traveller How so? Several non-EU/EFTA states allow EU ID cards for short-term visits (most of which nonetheless stamp EU passports). That said, Home Secretary Priti Patel does appear to be against accepting them

Comment: @user There won't be a 90/180 rule; instead in all likelihood you'll be allowed 6 months as a visitor liek e.g. Americans and Austraians

Comment: Sometime during 2021 a new system will be introduced in the Schengen Area. After that there will be no more stamping of passports for everyone.

Comment: @MarkJohnson IIRC stamps will remain available for spare in case of system failures

Comment: @Crazydre I think, in the long term, passports in their present form (booklets introduced in 1920), will be replaced with a card form.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Only doable once classic visas have ceased to exist.

Comment: @Crazydre Yes the 'International Passport' (as it was called in 1920) took 5 years to implement fully. Most countries that have a high amount of travelers already (or soon will) implement electronic  visas antry formalities.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Schengen, the UK, the US and Canada have no current plans to AFAIK (except the UK specifically for EU/EFTA citizens seeking to take up residency)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105913/discussion-between-mark-johnson-and-crazydre).

Answer (score 2):

Not decided yet, but likely you'll need a passport, as Home Secretary Priti Patel has vaguely claimed to be against accepting EU ID cards (though Gibraltar ID cards and Irish passport cards should remain OK). Again, though, not decided yet.

Comment: Was any reason given, taking into consideration that the technical data inside both are exactly the same? Seems like a gigantic waste of paper to me.

Comment: @MarkJohnson "Easy to forge", which I can't exactly disagree with. I did write her an electronic letter proposing that they start accepting biometric IDs only (listing which ones are). Kosovo and Moldova used to do this.

Comment: @MarkJohnson One important advantage of passports is that they are standard across all countries, and fields are properly labelled, while typically national ID cards will only label the fields in their own language. It makes for easier processing at the border.

Comment: @SJuan76 Well, ours are allready based on the card of a passport, just smaller and also in 3 languages. The chip information is the same and can be read with the same machines. A Passport card norm basically allready exists, it is just packed into a booklet.

Comment: @SJuan76 Most EU IDs are bilingual in English (the French one being one exception). Besides, when scanning a machine-readable card, the info on the screen is translated into the local language at the border crossing. Noticed it at the Magyarbóly and Kapikule rail stations as well as at Sabiha Gökcen airport, where the officers spoke zero English but could tell my nationality via the computer.